# Pell's equation fundamental solution vs. an earlier convergent of $\sqrt{d}$

Tags: continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

Let $(p,q)$ be the fundamental solution to Pell's equation $x^2-dy^2=1$, which makes $\frac{p}{q}$ a convergent of $\sqrt{d}$, per the theorem underlying the continued fraction algorithm for solving Pell's equation.

Is it always (or with finitely many exceptions) the case that at least one of the **reduced** fractions $\frac{p+1}{q},\frac{p-1}{q}$ is also a convergent of $\sqrt{d}$?

Examples:
$$
d=73\\
2281249^2-267000^2d=1\\
\frac{2281249-1}{267000}=\frac{1068}{125},\ a\ convergent\ of\ \sqrt{d}
$$

$$
d=95\\
39^2-4^2d=1\\
\frac{39+1}{4}=\frac{10}{1},\ a\ convergent\ of\ \sqrt{d}
$$

$$
d=96\\
49^2-5^2d=1\\
\frac{49+1}{5}=\frac{10}{1},\ a\ convergent\ of\ \sqrt{d}
$$

Comment: @Peter, I think you overlooked the word "reduced". I'll edit to emphasize the word and add a few examples where it is indeed the case. I checked a few $d$s and couldn't find one for which the conjecture of the question _doesn't_ hold.

Comment: @Peter yes, but we are NOT trying to use a numerator twice! We subtract or add $1$ from the denominator and then **reduce** the fraction, which reduces both the denominator **and** the numerator!

Comment: OK, now I got it. Sorry. Maybe , we can use however that the convergents are best approximations upto the denominator in the convergent.

Comment: There's a geometric interpretation to this: a line connecting the fundamental solution and one of the trivial solutions $(-1,0),\ (1,0)$.

Comment: I was initially confused by your inverted convergents, but it seems that you conjecture may be true. I just did a brute force test of all $1<d<5000$, using Sage.

Comment: [Sage script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtktFuwyAMRd_zFVanSbCxLI20l0p93VdMjUgwVZQKEkP2_TMkTVe1PHJ9Ltc2Bi1EDFEYBb9IrQ94_NaXgPJQAJ_OwhE672LvZjSNJd3F3jsRJmJGylzU2yt7gJF6F0VnFyXgxHzAKGSRL6wnGKB3bFyyLWNndDGI9bmVKbUxYpDb1agg-QylDg3b4xmpIc1BxK1m5oLxVMMHGHiD6VRvymO8QcEs_-sMH2F_y5COZkMxst9ewidM95ofWNWpEY57J7UL9v4MazPWPsMeQ2qVnlHQqsTJeyNCPeQbwjiTy4F4tFxYFGnGJr9B2p1R1Aq-qqpaR0xpIcv2rsuzF-9JkExDoMO27iy_LGF2P26nYEVyF8uv2TwMvMK-qpJFlZI4H7nuNtHFhn9ZaqVYTY13uJN_DSCmcg==&lang=sage)

Comment: You have everything upside down. E.g., $125/1068$ is **not** a convergent to $\sqrt{73}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Drats! That's what happens when you stare at the hyperbola and the slope of its asymptotes for too long! Fixed!

Comment: $p^2-dq^2=1$, $(p+1)(p-1)=dq^2$, $q^2$ divides $(p+1)(p-1)$, so there's going to be a lot of cancellation in at least one of $(p\pm1)/q$; its denominator, after the cancellation, will be fairly small. But it's $(p/q)\pm(1/q)$, so they are fairly close to $p/q$, hence, fairly close to $\sqrt d$. If they are close enough, there's a theorem that says they must be convergents.

Comment: Have you thought about my sketch of an approach, Szczepan?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes, I have, but honestly at this time the current events in the neighboring country displaced everything else on my mind that isn't my day job. I'll return to pursuing mathematics as a hobby in peace time.

Comment: OK. I wish you peace.